# How to specify the compiler flags to be used in "opt" compilation_mode by my own toolchain?

Tags: build, bazel

I have my own C/C++ toolchain and I am required to use a fixed set of gcc optimization flags (i.e. none of O1/2/3).  I would like to specify that these optimization flags are used by a `cc_binary` when I use compilation_mode "opt". How can I do this?

Answer (score 2):

For now I am doing the following in my BUILD file:

1. I have added a config setting:

   config_setting(
       name = "opt_mode",
       values = {
           "compilation_mode": "opt"
       }
   )
2. I am using the "select" function in my cc_library's "features" field / attribute / however that thing is called:

   select({
           ":opt_mode": ['foo', 'bar'],
           "//conditions:default": ['foobar']
       })

If this approach is totally bogus, please let me know; I am a complete Bazel newbie.

Comment: This approach looks fine to me. If you can set the optimization flags this way, go for it!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not a C++ rule expert, but I believe you have to define your own crosstool and use that in the build (see `--crosstool_top` flag).

Comment: Thanks, I have followed the tutorial https://docs.bazel.build/versions/master/toolchains.html to set up my toolchains and it works.  I have also added some features, which also seem to work :-).  Now I am especially interested in how to overwrite the compiler flags used in compilation_mode "opt" (and later on also "dbg", but I assume this should work similarly as for "opt").