# Building OpenCV with rules_foreign_cc

Tags: opencv, bazel, bazel-cpp

I want to start a new project in C++ with Bazel. To build OpenCV I want to use [foreign_rules_cc](https://bazelbuild.github.io/rules_foreign_cc/0.9.0/cmake.html).

I have followed some tutorials, but I have not been able to build opencv successfully.

This is my WORKSPACE:

```
workspace(name = "rules_foreign_cc_usage_example")

load("@bazel_tools//tools/build_defs/repo:http.bzl", "http_archive")

# Rule repository, note that it's recommended to use a pinned commit to a released version of the rules
http_archive(
   name = "rules_foreign_cc",
    sha256 = "2a4d07cd64b0719b39a7c12218a3e507672b82a97b98c6a89d38565894cf7c51",
   strip_prefix = "rules_foreign_cc-0.9.0",
   url = "https://github.com/bazelbuild/rules_foreign_cc/archive/refs/tags/0.9.0.tar.gz",
)

load("@rules_foreign_cc//foreign_cc:repositories.bzl", "rules_foreign_cc_dependencies")

# This sets up some common toolchains for building targets. For more details, please see
# https://github.com/bazelbuild/rules_foreign_cc/tree/main/docs#rules_foreign_cc_dependencies
rules_foreign_cc_dependencies()

_OPENCV_CONTENT = """\
filegroup(
    name = "all_srcs",
    srcs = glob(["**"]),
    visibility = ["//visibility:public"],
)
"""

http_archive(
    name = "opencv",
    build_file_content = _OPENCV_CONTENT,
    url = "https://github.com/opencv/opencv/archive/refs/tags/4.8.0.tar.gz",
    strip_prefix = "opencv-4.8.0",
)
```

This is my BUILD.bazel in the directory `thirdparty`:

```
load("@rules_foreign_cc//foreign_cc:defs.bzl", "cmake")
cmake(
    name = "libopencv",
    generate_args = [
        "-DBUILD_LIST=core,highgui,imgcodecs,imgproc",
        "-DBUILD_ZLIB=OFF",
    ],
    lib_source = "@opencv//:all_srcs",
)

filegroup(
    name = "opencv",
    srcs = [":libopencv"],
    visibility = ["//visibility:public"],
)
```

The error I get is

```
bazel build --explain=opencv.log --verbose_explanations //thirdparty:opencv
INFO: Analyzed target //thirdparty:opencv (49 packages loaded, 15164 targets configured).
INFO: Found 1 target...
INFO: Writing explanation of rebuilds to 'opencv.log'
ERROR: /Users/name/Code/Git/AimTracker/C/thirdparty/BUILD.bazel:2:6: output 'thirdparty/libopencv/lib/libopencv.a' was not created
ERROR: /Users/name/Code/Git/AimTracker/C/thirdparty/BUILD.bazel:2:6: Foreign Cc - CMake: Building libopencv failed: not all outputs were created or valid
Target //thirdparty:opencv failed to build
Use --verbose_failures to see the command lines of failed build steps.
INFO: Elapsed time: 292.206s, Critical Path: 290.73s
INFO: 7 processes: 5 internal, 2 darwin-sandbox.
FAILED: Build did NOT complete successfully
```

If I clone OpenCV, run

```
 cmake -DBUILD_ZLIB=OFF -DBUILD_LIST=core,highgui,imgcodecs,imgproc ..
 make
```

it compiles without any problems.

**UPDATE**

For Mac I followed the accepted answer below with some updates:

```
load("@rules_cc//cc:defs.bzl", "cc_library")
load("@rules_foreign_cc//foreign_cc:defs.bzl", "cmake")
cc_library(
    name = "opencv_deps",
    linkopts = [
        "-ldl", 
        "-lz", 
        "-lpthread",
        "-lavutil",
        "-lavformat", 
        "-lavcodec", 
        "-lswscale", 
        "-L/opt/homebrew/opt/ffmpeg/lib", 
        "-L/opt/homebrew/Cellar/libx11/1.8.6/lib", 
        "-framework Cocoa",
        "-framework Accelerate",
    ],
)

cmake(
    name = "opencv",
    build_args = [
        "-j16",
    ],
    cache_entries = {
        "OPENCV_FORCE_3RDPARTY_BUILD": "ON",
        "BUILD_SHARED_LIBS": "OFF",
        "BUILD_TESTS": "OFF",
        "BUILD_PERF_TESTS": "OFF",
        "BUILD_opencv_apps": "OFF",
        "BUILD_opencv_calib3d": "OFF",
        "BUILD_opencv_core": "ON",
        "BUILD_opencv_dnn": "OFF",
        "BUILD_opencv_features2d": "OFF",
        "BUILD_opencv_flann": "OFF",
        "BUILD_opencv_gapi": "OFF",
        "BUILD_opencv_highgui": "ON",
        "BUILD_opencv_imgcodecs": "ON",
        "BUILD_opencv_imgproc": "ON",
        "BUILD_opencv_java_bindings_generator": "OFF",
        "BUILD_opencv_js": "OFF",
        "BUILD_opencv_ml": "OFF",
        "BUILD_opencv_objdetect": "OFF",
        "BUILD_opencv_photo": "OFF",
        "BUILD_opencv_python_bindings_generator": "OFF",
        "BUILD_opencv_stitching": "OFF",
        "BUILD_opencv_ts": "OFF",
        "BUILD_opencv_video": "OFF",
        "BUILD_opencv_videoio": "ON",
        "BUILD_opencv_world": "ON",
        "BUILD_IPP_IW": "ON",
        "WITH_ADE": "OFF",
        "WITH_CAROTENE": "OFF",
        "WITH_IPP": "OFF",
        "WITH_ITT": "ON",
        "WITH_OPENEXR": "OFF",
        "WITH_JASPER": "OFF",
        "WITH_JPEG": "OFF",
        "WITH_OPENJPEG": "ON",
        "WITH_TIFF": "OFF",
        "WITH_WEBP": "ON",
        "WITH_QUIRC": "ON",
        "WITH_GTK": "OFF",
        "WITH_OPENBLAS": "ON",
        "WITH_OPENCL": "OFF",
    },
    env = {
        "CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE": "Release",
        "CMAKE_BUILD_PARALLEL_LEVEL": "16",
    },
    lib_source = "@opencv//:all",
    out_include_dir = "include/opencv4",
    out_static_libs = [
        "libopencv_world.a",
        "opencv4/3rdparty/libittnotify.a",
        "opencv4/3rdparty/liblibopenjp2.a",
        "opencv4/3rdparty/liblibwebp.a",
        "opencv4/3rdparty/liblibpng.a",
    ],
    targets = [
        "install",
    ],
    visibility = ["//visibility:public"],
    deps = [":opencv_deps"],
)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is my BUILD file that works (at least for me) with ubuntu 22.04.

```
load("@rules_cc//cc:defs.bzl", "cc_library")
load("@rules_foreign_cc//foreign_cc:defs.bzl", "cmake")

cc_library(
    name = "opencv_deps",
    linkopts = [
        "-ldl",
        "-lz",
        "-lpthread",
        "-ldc1394",
        "-lavutil",
        "-lavformat",
        "-lavcodec",
        "-lswscale",
    ],
)

cmake(
    name = "opencv",
    build_args = [
        "-j16",
    ],
    cache_entries = {
        "OPENCV_FORCE_3RDPARTY_BUILD": "ON",
        "BUILD_SHARED_LIBS": "OFF",
        "BUILD_TESTS": "OFF",
        "BUILD_PERF_TESTS": "OFF",
        "BUILD_opencv_apps": "OFF",
        "BUILD_opencv_calib3d": "OFF",
        "BUILD_opencv_core": "ON",
        "BUILD_opencv_dnn": "OFF",
        "BUILD_opencv_features2d": "OFF",
        "BUILD_opencv_flann": "OFF",
        "BUILD_opencv_gapi": "OFF",
        "BUILD_opencv_highgui": "ON",
        "BUILD_opencv_imgcodecs": "ON",
        "BUILD_opencv_imgproc": "ON",
        "BUILD_opencv_java_bindings_generator": "OFF",
        "BUILD_opencv_js": "OFF",
        "BUILD_opencv_ml": "OFF",
        "BUILD_opencv_objdetect": "OFF",
        "BUILD_opencv_photo": "OFF",
        "BUILD_opencv_python_bindings_generator": "OFF",
        "BUILD_opencv_stitching": "OFF",
        "BUILD_opencv_ts": "OFF",
        "BUILD_opencv_video": "OFF",
        "BUILD_opencv_videoio": "ON",
        "BUILD_opencv_world": "ON",
        "BUILD_IPP_IW": "ON",
        "WITH_ADE": "OFF",
        "WITH_CAROTENE": "OFF",
        "WITH_IPP": "OFF",
        "WITH_ITT": "ON",
        "WITH_OPENEXR": "OFF",
        "WITH_JASPER": "OFF",
        "WITH_JPEG": "OFF",
        "WITH_OPENJPEG": "ON",
        "WITH_TIFF": "OFF",
        "WITH_WEBP": "ON",
        "WITH_QUIRC": "ON",
        "WITH_GTK": "OFF",
    },
    env = {
        "CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE": "Release",
        "CMAKE_BUILD_PARALLEL_LEVEL": "16",
    },
    lib_source = "@opencv//:all",
    out_include_dir = "include/opencv4",
    out_static_libs = [
        "libopencv_world.a",
        "opencv4/3rdparty/libittnotify.a",
        "opencv4/3rdparty/liblibopenjp2.a",
        "opencv4/3rdparty/liblibwebp.a",
        "opencv4/3rdparty/liblibpng.a",
    ],
    targets = [
        "install",
    ],
    visibility = ["//visibility:public"],
    deps = [":opencv_deps"],
)
```

WORKSPACE snippet:

```
all_content = """filegroup(
    name = "all",
    srcs = glob(["**"]),
    visibility = ["//visibility:public"]
)
"""

http_archive(
    name = "rules_foreign_cc",
    sha256 = "2a4d07cd64b0719b39a7c12218a3e507672b82a97b98c6a89d38565894cf7c51",
    strip_prefix = "rules_foreign_cc-0.9.0",
    url = "https://github.com/bazelbuild/rules_foreign_cc/archive/refs/tags/0.9.0.tar.gz",
)

load("@rules_foreign_cc//foreign_cc:repositories.bzl", "rules_foreign_cc_dependencies")

rules_foreign_cc_dependencies()

http_archive(
    name = "opencv",
    build_file_content = all_content,
    sha256 = "a61e7a4618d353140c857f25843f39b2abe5f451b018aab1604ef0bc34cd23d5",
    strip_prefix = "opencv-4.5.3",
    urls = [
        "https://github.com/opencv/opencv/archive/4.5.3.zip",
    ],
)
```

Comment: Thanks, when I try this on my Mac then `Bazel build //thirdparty:opencv` works. But when I try and add `opencv`as a dependency to my `src/BUILD.bazel` file I get:

`external/local_config_cc/cc_wrapper.sh @bazel-out/darwin_arm64 -fastbuild/bin/src/main-2.params)ld: library not found for -ldc1394`


In `/opt/homebrew/lib/` I have `libdc1394.26.dylib@ libdc1394.a@ libdc1394.dylib@ `

Comment: I solved it by adding "-L/opt/homebrew/lib" to linkopts.

Comment: But there are some other issues with OpenBlas and arm64. I am looking into it.

Comment: For apple silicon, my opencv_deps look like this:

```
cc_library(
    name = "opencv_deps",
    linkopts = [
        "-ldl",
        "-lz",
        "-lpthread",
        #        "-ldc1394",
        "-lavutil",
        "-lavformat",
        "-lavcodec",
        "-lswscale",
        "-L/opt/homebrew/opt/ffmpeg/lib",
        "-L/opt/X11/lib",
        "-framework Cocoa",
    ],
)
```

Comment: Thanks, I added "-framework Accelerate" and change /opt/X11/lib to /opt/homebrew/libx11/1.8.6/lib. Not sure if that is the same, I don't have /opt/X11/.

But know I get:

`Undefined symbols for architecture arm64:
  "_clBuildProgram", referenced from:
      _clBuildProgram_pfn`

Comment: I added "WITH_OPENCL": "OFF" and now it works! Thanks a lot!

Comment: Thanks, this also worked for me. I did have to install `ffmpeg` to get it working (`brew install ffmpeg`).

Comment: If anyone finds a way to not need to install `ffmpeg`, that would be great to know. Because right now the solution above does not work on CI out of the box (because the build is not fully hermetic).

Comment: You could try WITH_FFMPEG=OFF in the cmake cache_entries. See https://docs.opencv.org/4.x/db/d05/tutorial_config_reference.html

Answer (score 1):

One another approach is **not** to use `rules_foreign_cc`. This worked for me in the past with Visual Studio on Windows:

*WORKSPACE.bazel*:

```
workspace(name = "OpenCVDemo")

load("@bazel_tools//tools/build_defs/repo:http.bzl", "http_archive")

# OpenCV
http_archive(
    name = "opencv",
    build_file = "//third_party:opencv.BUILD",
    strip_prefix = "opencv/build",
    # Debug
    #url = "http://vertexwahn.de/artifacts/opencv-4.3.0-dldt-2020.2-vc16-avx2-debug.zip",
    #sha256 = "9bcd2dda258e67ad2ddef7768f1c9b2afcc68cd4b9d9f5c9b841ea3ee47f9d4c",
    # Release
    url = "https://github.com/opencv/opencv/releases/download/4.3.0/opencv-4.3.0-dldt-2020.2-vc16-avx2.zip",
)
```

*third_party/opencv.BUILD*:

```
package(default_visibility = ["//visibility:public"])

MAIN_MODULES = [
    "core",
    "imgproc",
    "imgcodecs",
    "videoio",
    "highgui",
    "video",
    "calib3d",
    "features2d",
    "objdetect",
    "dnn",
    "ml",
    "flann",
    "photo",
    "stitching",
    "gapi",
]

# https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56108940/how-to-specify-the-compiler-flags-to-be-used-in-opt-compilation-mode-by-my-own
config_setting(
    name = "fastbuild_mode",
    values = {"compilation_mode": "fastbuild"},
)

config_setting(
    name = "dbg_mode",
    values = {"compilation_mode": "dbg"},
)

cc_import(
    name = "tbb",
    shared_library = select({
        ":fastbuild_mode": "bin/tbb.dll",
        ":dbg_mode": "bin/tbb_debug.dll",
        "//conditions:default": "bin/tbb.dll",
    }),
)

[
    (
        cc_import(
            name = module,
            interface_library = select({
                ":fastbuild_mode": "lib/opencv_{}430.lib".format(module),
                ":dbg_mode": "lib/opencv_{}430d.lib".format(module),
                "//conditions:default": "lib/opencv_{}430.lib".format(module),
            }),
            shared_library = select({
                ":fastbuild_mode": "bin/opencv_{}430.dll".format(module),
                ":dbg_mode": "bin/opencv_{}430d.dll".format(module),
                "//conditions:default": "bin/opencv_{}430.dll".format(module),
            }),
        )
    )
    for module in MAIN_MODULES
]

cc_library(
    name = "opencv",
    hdrs = [
        "include/opencv2/calib3d.hpp",
        "include/opencv2/calib3d/calib3d.hpp",
        "include/opencv2/calib3d/calib3d_c.h",
        "include/opencv2/core.hpp",
        "include/opencv2/core/hal/interface.h",
        "include/opencv2/cvconfig.h",
        "include/opencv2/dnn.hpp",
        "include/opencv2/features2d.hpp",
        "include/opencv2/flann.hpp",
        "include/opencv2/flann/config.h",
        "include/opencv2/flann/defines.h",
        "include/opencv2/flann/miniflann.hpp",
        "include/opencv2/highgui.hpp",
        "include/opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp",
        "include/opencv2/highgui/highgui_c.h",
        "include/opencv2/imgcodecs.hpp",
        "include/opencv2/imgproc.hpp",
        "include/opencv2/ml.hpp",
        "include/opencv2/ml/ml.inl.hpp",
        "include/opencv2/objdetect.hpp",
        "include/opencv2/opencv.hpp",
        "include/opencv2/opencv_modules.hpp",
        "include/opencv2/photo.hpp",
        "include/opencv2/stitching.hpp",
        "include/opencv2/video.hpp",
        "include/opencv2/video/background_segm.hpp",
        "include/opencv2/video/tracking.hpp",
        "include/opencv2/videoio.hpp",
        "include/opencv2/videoio/videoio_c.h",
    ],
    includes = ["include"],
    deps = MAIN_MODULES + [
        "tbb",
    ],
)
```

*third_party/BUILD.bazel*

```
# empty by intend
```

*BUILD.bazel*:

```
cc_binary(
    name = "OpenCVDemo",
    srcs = ["main.cpp"],
    deps = ["@opencv"],
)
```