# Building OpenCV with Bazel rules_foreign_cc

Tags: cmake, bazel

I want to integrate OpenCV in my Bazel workspace through rules_foreign_cc and I found this other [stack overflow thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76795829/1638795) that discusses the general setup very well. I followed the setup resulting in a successful build of my workspace. However, when executing the generated binary I am getting the following error:

`... while loading shared libraries: libopencv_world.so.408: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory`

I found two folders the depths of the bazel_out:

```
opencv/libs/ containing libopencv_world.so
copy_opencv/libs/ containing libopencv_world.so, libopencv_world.so.408, and libopencv_world.so.481.
```

General system info: Ubuntu 22.04 / Bazel 6.1.1

Given that the libraries are created I would assume that there is something wrong with how I am setting up the binary. This is my workspace:

```
├── opencv_demo
│   ├── opencv_demo.BUILD
│   └── main.cpp
├── third_party
│   ├── BUILD
│   └── opencv.BUILD
└── WORKSPACE
```

WORKSPACE snippet:

```
load("@rules_foreign_cc//foreign_cc:repositories.bzl", "rules_foreign_cc_dependencies")
rules_foreign_cc_dependencies()

http_archive(
    name = "opencv",
    build_file = "//third_party:opencv.BUILD",
    sha256 = "62f650467a60a38794d681ae7e66e3e8cfba38f445e0bf87867e2f2cdc8be9d5",
    strip_prefix = "opencv-4.8.1",
    urls = ["https://github.com/opencv/opencv/archive/refs/tags/4.8.1.tar.gz"],
)
```

opencv.BUILD:

```
load("@rules_foreign_cc//foreign_cc:defs.bzl", "cmake")

filegroup(
    name = "all_srcs",
    srcs = glob(["**"]),
)

cmake(
    name = "opencv",
    build_args = [
        "-j16",
    ],
    generate_args = ["-GNinja"],
    cache_entries = {
        "BUILD_opencv_world": "ON",
        "BUILD_SHARED_LIBS": "ON",
    },
    env = {
        "CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE": "Release",
        "CMAKE_BUILD_PARALLEL_LEVEL": "16",
    },
    lib_source = "all_srcs",
    out_include_dir = "include/opencv4",

    **EDIT BEGIN**
    # out_shared_libs = ["libopencv_world.so"],
    out_shared_libs = [
        "libopencv_world.so",
        "libopencv_world.so.4.8.1",
        "libopencv_world.so.408",
    ],
    **EDIT END**

    visibility = ["//visibility:public"],
)
```

opencv_demo.BUILD

```
cc_binary(
    name = "OpenCVDemo",
    srcs = ["main.cpp"],
    deps = ["@opencv"],
)
```

main.cpp

```
#include "opencv2/core.hpp"
#include "opencv2/imgproc.hpp"
#include "opencv2/highgui.hpp"

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    cv::Mat img(100, 100, CV_8UC3);
    cv::randu(img, cv::Scalar(0, 0, 0), cv::Scalar(255, 255, 255));

    cv::imshow("random colors image", img);
    cv::waitKey();

    return 0;
}
```

Executing the binary:
`./bazel-bin/opencv_demo/OpenCVDemo`

**Update:**
Running `bazel aquery opencv_demo:OpenCVDemo` shows the path of the shared library: `bazel-out/k8-fastbuild/bin/_solib_k8/_U@opencv_S_S_Copencv___Uexternal_Sopencv_Sopencv_Slib/libopencv_world.so`. This path only contains the `libopencv_world.so`. Copying the two other so's `libopencv_world.so.408` and `libopencv_world.so.4.8.1` into that folder solves the issue.

I changed the `opencv.BUILD` (see above) but that is rather messy. Is there a way to fix this without explicitly adding the "versioned" shared libraries to the cmake rule?